# Firestore iterating though a document to find null fields

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am implementing a feature into my app that allows users to view there ongoing discussions about a post. I want the user to only be able to have 5 active discussions.(When the discussion is being created i want to be able to check the users document to see if they have exceeded the maximum allowed discussions This is what i am working with

```
currentDocument.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {

                if (document.get("PostID 1") == null) {

                    //No discussion post in this field

                } if (document.get("PostID 2") == null){

                   //No discussion post in this field

                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

for this to work i would have to create an if statement for every document field this seems like poor programming practice to me. Is there a better way to go about this or should i tackle the problem a different way all suggestions welcome!

document:

[image]

Update:

Getting close to my solution but still stuck

I get my document with

```
currentDocument.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

}
```

I get the document data and store it

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

Map test = document.getData(); }
```

And i itterate through it

```
for (Object entry : test.entrySet() ){

Log.w(TAG, "Key = " + entry.toString()); }
```

up to this point i am good where i am now stuck is i want to have an if statement  to determine if the value is null or not this is what i am working with

```
for (Object entry : test.entrySet() ){

        Log.w(TAG, "Key = " + entry.toString());

    if (entry.toString().contains(null)){

        Log.w(TAG, entry.toString() + " is equal to null");

    }

}
```

it throws the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
```

I believe that I am not correctly reading the data in the if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot), you can call [getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getData()) on it to get a [Map](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map) of all the fields and values.  Then you just iterate it as you would any other Java Map using its [entrySet()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map#entrySet()).

Comment: If you have a followup question that's different than the first, it's customary to post a new question with the new problem.  What you did was edit the question to actually just ask a whole new question, which is not really the way Stack Overflow works.